# During a basketball game, what rules prevent players from acting in distracting/heckling ways to throw off opponents?

Tags: rules, basketball, officiating, nba

During a freethrow, [distracting the shooter is clearly disallowed according to the rules](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/27825/23757). But during the game, what is preventing players from trying to distract each other? For example, by screaming just as someone tries to make a shot, or pretend like they're having a spasm. To take it to the extreme, players could scream expletives, or insulting each others family in undertones, to distract and throw each other off (or invite a foul).

What rules are preventing this sort of behavior in the NBA? Or are the only incentives indirect ones, like losing deals and sponsors if you act that way?